# How do I make quotes look like quotes in a string

Tags: mysql

As a user I input this into the string $description: “This is one of those books that you don’t want to put down …” Romantic Times

This is what appears in the description field of my record: **â€œThis is one of those books that you donâ€™t want to put down â€¦â€ Romantic Times**

This is what the mysql record looks like:
Field=description,  Type= TEXT,   Length/Values= "empty",   Collation= utf8_general_ci

Why does it display those weird characters? Is it the utf8_general_ci setting?

Comment: You're reading UTF8 bytes as a single-byte encoding.  Change your code to use UTF8 everywhere.

Comment: Not enough information. Which programming language and db API do you use?

Comment: I'm inputing with a regular html form and this code: <textarea name="description" id="description" cols="30" rows="15"><?php echo $description; ?></textarea>

Comment: On submit it is parsed with $description = $_POST['description']; and inserted into my Mysql database with INSERT INTO

Answer (score 1):

They are smart quotes. Use normal quotes like this "

Comment: To be clear, "Smart quotes" is just a feature of your editor that automatically uses proper quotes instead of the generic ones. In a typographical sense, `"` is used for things like inches, not quotations.

Comment: Is there a way to remove smart quotes from a string like I removed "\" from my string with $description = stripslashes($description);  or maybe a way to prevent the html form from putting smart quotes into my string in the first place?

Comment: You should stop the input form from allowing smart quotes (curly quotes) and only allow straight quotes.